# Firebase rules access to data

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm going to create app to share photo albums, using firebase. 
Now I've issue with securing common objects.

My data object is

```
"Album" : {
"AbAY6YVhy6MLyvVjyYC517v62o22" : {
  "-KeD0I9C-esXW2zA4uH_" : {
    "backgroundPattern" : 0,
    "collaboratorsIDS" : 
        [ "cS5O4Klt8CXrrKLJPVkHMaSTltW2","J55nZlr4SSPHL5GW7c7yrUkbAUl1", "LQ5mNECXAMQi9AoLCXh8GMsihf12" ],
    "date" : "2017-03-02",
    "direction" : 2,
    "imageUrl" : "",
    "ownerID" : "AbAY6YVhy6MLyvVjyYC517v62o22",
    "scrapBookID" : "-KeD0I9C-esXW2zA4uH_",
    "title" : "Test"
  }
}
```

And question is, how to set **.read** and **.write** rules for albums. Main point is that **collaboratorsIDS** is user ID's that should have access to album.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Album": {
      "$albumId" : {
        "$pushKey" : {
          ".read":"data.child('collaboratorsIDS').val().contains(auth.uid)"
        }
      }
```

With this, you can allow access to your node for collaboratorsIDS